# Mongoose Transactions and Post Transactional Operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using `mongoose` together with `sessions` to perform ACID transactions in our `nodejs` + `express` backend.

lately, I have a necessity to send a message to one of our workers (backed by RabbitMQ) to make post transactional operation. I cannot directly send the message to our worker after the commit because there is a complex workflow behind it and completing the transaction does not always mean that the code must be called.

I believe that I need to use event emitters to register `.once('onCommit', ...)` event, and call `emit('onCommit')` when the transaction is done. But this is manual approach.

I would like to know if there is out of the box support in `mongoose` to make post transactional operations using `mongoose.ClientSession`. I am seeing that mongoose sessions are by itself Event Listeners but I couldn't find any related docuementation. I guess session events are for internal use.

can anyone enlighten me?

thank you

Comment: "out of the box"  method for post-transaction operations is to follow the promise chain. Once `commitTransaction` or `withTransaction` is resolved it calls post-transaction code. Mongoose adds nothing on top of the driver's functions, and both call  [endTransaction](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/af36ebbbe231722ed55b53d3dece5567e281587a/src/sessions.ts#L659) under the hood.  There is no magic there - just some validation and error handling around `commitTransaction` command and return control to the caller.

Comment: Event Listeners works better in this case. because otherwise, I need to know which condition(s) satisfied in order to fire related post transactional operation(s). I solved it but I was curios if I can use session object itself since it is extended from EventEmitter

Comment: yes, I get the idea, and it seems to make sense in your case =) I shared the link to session.ts to make it obvious it emits only session-related events - pinned, ended, etc. take a look, it's straightforward and very readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `ended` event. So below code should work if you finalize the transaction operation with `session.endSession();`

```
session.on('ended', () => 'post transaction operation');
```

Additionally if you need an information about transaction committed or aborted. You can get the post session data and check transaction state like below:

```
session.on('ended', (postSession) => {
    const state = postSession.transaction.state;

    if (state === 'TRANSACTION_COMMITTED') {
      'successful transaction operation';
    }

    if (state === 'TRANSACTION_ABORTED') {
      'aborted transaction operation';
    }
 });
```

Comment: Hey, I handled it differently but I find this answer more optimal. so I am accepting it. Thank you for your contribution